# Check if string ends with certain pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

If I have a string like:

```
This.is.a.great.place.too.work.
```

or:

```
This/is/a/great/place/too/work/
```

than my program should give me that the sentence is valid and it has "work".

If I Have :

```
This.is.a.great.place.too.work.hahahha
```

or:

```
This/is/a/great/place/too/work/hahahah
```

then my program should not give me that there is a "work" in the sentence.

So I am looking at java strings to find a word at the end of the sentence having `.` or `,` or `/` before it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have some great answers below, @Learner; you should select one and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 96):

This is really simple, the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) object has an [`endsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) method.

From your question it seems like you want either `/`, `,` or `.` as the delimiter set.

So:

```
String str = "This.is.a.great.place.to.work.";

if (str.endsWith(".work.") || str.endsWith("/work/") || str.endsWith(",work,"))
     // ...
```

You can also do this with the [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method and a fairly simple regex:

```
if (str.matches(".*([.,/])work\\1$"))
```

Using the character class `[.,/]` specifying either a period, a slash, or a comma, and a backreference, `\1` that matches whichever of the alternates were found, if any.

Comment: Seems like neither of these answers account for an extra char at the end like OP specified.

Comment: Thanks pb2q that answers by question as I do not know what the end character is (my issue is at the end there will be only character (,/$..)or may not be  But will not be a word. so in java  can u explan me what is 1$

Comment: @TheLearner two separate things at the regex end: the first is `\1`, which is a backreference, referring to whichever character was matched from the character set [,./] earlier in the regex; we surround that set with parens to group it as referenceable: `([,./])`. And the `$` just means _end of line_.

Answer (score 56):

You can test if a string ends with *work* followed by one character like this:

```
theString.matches(".*work.$");
```

If the trailing character is **optional** you can use this:

```
theString.matches(".*work.?$");
```

To make sure the last character is a period `.` or a slash `/` you can use this:

```
theString.matches(".*work[./]$");
```

To test for *work* followed by an **optional** period or slash you can use this:

```
theString.matches(".*work[./]?$");
```

To test for *work* **surrounded** by periods **or** slashes, you could do this:

```
theString.matches(".*[./]work[./]$");
```

If the **tokens before and after** *work* **must match each other**, you could do this:

```
theString.matches(".*([./])work\\1$");
```

---

Your exact requirement isn't precisely defined, but I think it would be something like this:

```
theString.matches(".*work[,./]?$");
```

In other words:

- zero or more characters
- followed by *work*
- followed by zero or one `,` `.` **OR** `/`
- followed by the end of the input

---

Explanation of various regex items:

```
.               --  any character
*               --  zero or more of the preceeding expression
$               --  the end of the line/input
?               --  zero or one of the preceeding expression
[./,]           --  either a period or a slash or a comma
[abc]           --  matches a, b, or c
[abc]*          --  zero or more of (a, b, or c)
[abc]?          --  zero or one of (a, b, or c)

enclosing a pattern in parentheses is called "grouping"

([abc])blah\\1  --  a, b, or c followed by blah followed by "the first group"
```

---

Here's a test harness to play with:

```
class TestStuff {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String[] testStrings = { 
                "work.",
                "work-",
                "workp",
                "/foo/work.",
                "/bar/work",
                "baz/work.",
                "baz.funk.work.",
                "funk.work",
                "jazz/junk/foo/work.",
                "funk/punk/work/",
                "/funk/foo/bar/work",
                "/funk/foo/bar/work/",
                ".funk.foo.bar.work.",
                ".funk.foo.bar.work",
                "goo/balls/work/",
                "goo/balls/work/funk"
        };

        for (String t : testStrings) {
            print("word: " + t + "  --->  " + matchesIt(t));
        }
    }

    public static boolean matchesIt(String s) {
        return s.matches(".*([./,])work\\1?$");
    }

    public static void print(Object o) {
        String s = (o == null) ? "null" : o.toString();
        System.out.println(o);
    }

}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks for the informative response.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use the [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class to split the String with '.' or '/', and check if the last word is "work".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substring method:

```
   String aString = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work.";
   String aSubstring = "work";
   String endString = aString.substring(aString.length() - 
        (aSubstring.length() + 1),aString.length() - 1);
   if ( endString.equals(aSubstring) )
       System.out.println("Equal " + aString + " " + aSubstring);
   else
       System.out.println("NOT equal " + aString + " " + aSubstring);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String input1 = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work.";
    String input2 = "This/is/a/great/place/too/work/";
    String input3 = "This,is,a,great,place,too,work,";
    String input4 = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work.hahahah";
    String input5 = "This/is/a/great/place/too/work/hahaha";
    String input6 = "This,is,a,great,place,too,work,hahahha";
    
    String regEx = ".*work[.,/]";
    
    System.out.println(input1.matches(regEx)); // true
    System.out.println(input2.matches(regEx)); // true
    System.out.println(input3.matches(regEx)); // true
    System.out.println(input4.matches(regEx)); // false
    System.out.println(input5.matches(regEx)); // false
    System.out.println(input6.matches(regEx)); // false
```

Comment: The regular expression will make sure that the input string is ending with "work" followed by just one character, that last character should be one of the three allowed allowed characters(comma, period or the forward slash).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the different things mentioned here to get the index of the `.` character in a filename that ends with `.[0-9][0-9]*`, e.g. `srcfile.1`, `srcfile.12`, etc. Nothing worked. Finally, the following worked: 
`int dotIndex = inputfilename.lastIndexOf(".");`

Weird! This is with java -version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.10.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Also, the official Java doc page for `regex` (from which there is a quote in one of the answers above) does not seem to specify how to look for the `.` character. Because `\.`, `\\.`, and `[.]` did not work for me, and I don't see any other options specified apart from these.

Comment: Turns out "\\." in a regex (regular expression) works, if you are looking for the dot character. The difficulty arose for me from the non-uniform API of Java String: for the task of locating/extracting the version number from a file name string, I would consider the String methods .endsWith(), .contains(), and lastly .matches. Turns out that each takes a different argument type, so things can get confusing: .endsWith(String), .contains(CharSequence), and .matches(regex)!