# Match String ending with (regex) java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am following the suggestions on the page, [check if string ends with certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310978/check-if-string-ends-with-certain-pattern)

I am trying to display a string that is

- Starts with anything
- Has the letters "**.mp4**" in it
- Ends explicitly with    **',** (apostrophe followed by comma)

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        String str = " _file='ANyTypEofSTR1ngHere_133444556_266545797_10798866.mp4',";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*.mp4[',]$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if(m.find())
            System.out.println("yes");
        else
            System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

It prints "no". How should I declare my RegEx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your regex:

1. "Has the letters `.mp4` in it" means somewhere, not necessarily just in front of `',`, so another `.*` should be inserted.
2. `.` matches any character. Use `\.` to match `.`
3. `[,']` is a character group, i.e. exactly one of the characters in the brackets has to occur.

You can use the following regex instead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\.mp4.*',$");
```

Comment: Thanks.Really clear.
Why was that backslash used,just before using **\.** to match a dot

Comment: @Pradeep: Since `.` in a regex matches any character, but you only want to match the string, if it contains `.mp4` as substring, you need to use `\.mp4`, since otherwise it matches strings containing `xmp4`, but not `.mp4` too. The double backslash just escapes a single backslash

Answer (score 3):

Your character set `[',]` is checking whether the string ends with `'` or `,` a single time.

If you want to match those character one or more times, use `[',]+`. However, you probably don't want to use a character set in this case since you said order is important.

To match an apostrophe followed by comma, just use:

```
.*\\.mp4',$
```

Also, since `.` has special meaning, you need to escape it in '.mp4'.