# Searching a text file to find all the words that ends with "ing" using java

Tags: java

I have been trying to write a program that reads a text file and searches for a words that ends with 'ing' using java but I could not done it. Also display words that are accepted "*ends with ing*" and rejected word "*doesnot end with ing*".

[image]

Comment: `I have been trying` can you share your tries ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if string ends with certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310978/check-if-string-ends-with-certain-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

This link https://stackabuse.com/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-java/ shows you how to get data from a txt file. I implemented the code that searches for the "accepted" strings and the "rejected" strings as well. The way that the code works is that I use the .substring() method to check the last 3 characters of the string, and if it is 'ing', then I add it to the "accepted" string, and if not, I add it to the "notAccepted" string.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class StackOverflowQuestion{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("yourFileName.txt"));
        String st = "";
        String st2 = "";
        String accepted = "";
        String notAccepted = "";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            st= scanner.next();
            if(st.length() <= 3){
               notAccepted += st + " ";
               continue;
            } else {
               st2 = st.substring(st.length() - 3,st.length());
            }
            if(st2.equals("ing")){
               accepted += st + " ";
            } else {
               notAccepted += st + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List of accepted strings ie ending with 'ing': " + accepted);
        System.out.println("List of rejected strings ie not ending with 'ing': " + notAccepted);
   }
}
```

You need to have the "throws Exception" code just in case the file isn't found. To make sure that you get strings that are equal to or less than 3 characters long, you need to check that before you make the substrings. Hope it helped!

Comment: this is so useful thanks, but unfortunately it does not read words that is less than 3 letters. when I read a text file which contains a words with less than 3 letters it gives me error.

Comment: I fixed the error! @DiyarMhamad